# JSON Parsing and Displaying

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, web, dart

I have an API that is returning JSON.  I'm having issues on where to start getting this idea off the ground.  I won't have to be saving any information into a database and i'm just displaying it.  I think I may be overthinking this with an angular project, but what would be the easiest way to accomplish this task?

EDIT:

I'm not creating an API, I'm just using one that the web address returns the JSON string.  What I'm having difficulty doing is wrapping my head around returning it to browser in a pretty viewable format.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This question is **way** too abstract. Please add concrete code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific on what you are wanting. Are you looking for a json parsing library? are you asking how to print json, read json objects, what are you displaying it in?

Comment: Literally: `res.send(JSON.stringify(myObj));`

Comment: The easiest? Visit the APi in your webbrowser and it will show you a nice colorful formatted json tree.

Comment: @JonasW. I think his question is about creating an API that returns a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The easy answer is you don't.**

While its dead simple to create "pretty JSON" by just:

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    respond_to do |f|
       f.json { render json: JSON.pretty_generate({ "hello": "world" }) }
    end
  end
end
```

all that whitespace just eats up bandwidth. Plus it adds a lot of complexity if you´re actually rendering collections of models or using `ActiveModel::Serializers` or `JBuilder`. There are plenty of tools like Postman or even just a browser that can be used instead to view the output JSON in a pleasant way.

[image: Postman]

If you just want to render JSON from a arbitrary Ruby hash or array just pass it to [`render json:`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-json)

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    respond_to do |f|
       f.json { render json: { "hello": "world" } }
    end
  end
end
```